# iOS 7: What is UIBarButtonItem's default font?

Tags: uikit, uibarbuttonitem, ios7, uifont, uibarbuttonitemstyle

What is the default font of the `title` of a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `style` of `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone`?

The following just returns `nil`:

`[doneBarButtonItem titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]`

Answer (score 13):

`[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]`

Note: I confirmed this by doing:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
[doneBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And then, I took screenshots of the before & after and compared them. They were identical.

Comment: This doesn't take into account iOS 7's Dynamic Type sizing information.

Comment: Good point. Although, that doesn't appear to affect `UIBarButtonItem` title font. In any case, the slider in Settings > General > Text Size was directly in the middle upon precisely confirming this answer.

Comment: Plus this could change in the future (if it hasn't already). Not really an acceptable answer. There needs to be a way to get it programatically

Comment: Maybe it changed since 2013, but this is not true anymore. [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] seems to be ok now (not sure I'm just comparing screenshots)

Answer (score 13):

You can retrieve the default font for a UILabel (which includes UIBarButton's title label) by querying

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.labelFontSize)
```